# Comparing strings of B and C, D and A returning true

Tags: java, graph-algorithm

Hey im in the final touches of my program now, and i have come across the weirdest bug, basically i am comparing 2 objects which both contain two strings, so i am comparing all the combinations of the strings together to see if the objects are relating by a common string.

It's for a kruskals cycle checker so its a little more complex than that but thats the basics of this error, i have added some manual system.out debugs and its telling me the weirdest things, for example this is the base of it, it only compares label1 to label1 but it is repeated for 
1 1
1 2
2 1
2 2

```
private static ArrayList<Graph> caseForConnection(
        Connection consideredConnection, ArrayList<Graph> subTrees)
        throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Graph> ret = new ArrayList<Graph>();
    System.out.println("Considering connection " +consideredConnection.getSaveDetails()[1] +consideredConnection.getSaveDetails()[2] + "  "+consideredConnection.getSaveDetails()[3]);
    String label1 = consideredConnection.getNode(1).getLabel();
    String label2 = consideredConnection.getNode(2).getLabel();
    for (Graph x : subTrees) {
        for (Connection c : x.getConnectionList()) {
            System.out.println("Comparing to connection "+  c.getSaveDetails()[1] +c.getSaveDetails()[2] +"  " +c.getSaveDetails()[3]);
            if (c.getNode(1)
                    .getLabel()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(label1)) {
                if (ret.contains(x)) {
                    System.out.print(("Found " + c.getNode(1)
                            .getLabel() +" is the same as " + label1+ " And this is twice"));
                    throw new Exception("Cycle Found");
                }
                System.out.print(("Found " + c.getNode(1)
                        .getLabel() +" is the same as " + label1));
                ret.add(x);
            } else if (c
                    .getNode(1)
                    .getLabel()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(label2)) {
                if (ret.contains(x)) {
                    System.out.print(("Found " + c.getNode(1)
                            .getLabel() +" is the same as " + label1+ " And this is twice"));
                    throw new Exception("Cycle Found");
                }
                System.out.print(("Found " + c.getNode(1)
                        .getLabel() +" is the same as " + label2));
                ret.add(x);
            }
            if (c.getNode(2)
                    .getLabel()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(label1)) {
                if (ret.contains(x)) {
                    System.out.print(("Found " + c.getNode(1)
                            .getLabel() +" is the same as " + label1+ " And this is twice"));
                    throw new Exception("Cycle Found");
                }
                System.out.print(("Found " + c.getNode(2)
                        .getLabel() +" is the same as " + label1));
                ret.add(x);
            } else if (c
                    .getNode(2)
                    .getLabel()
                    .equalsIgnoreCase(label2)) {
                if (ret.contains(x)) {
                    System.out.print(("Found " + c.getNode(1)
                            .getLabel() +" is the same as " + label1+ " And this is twice"));
                    throw new Exception("Cycle Found");
                }
                System.out.print(("Found " + c.getNode(2)
                        .getLabel() +" is the same as " + label2));
                ret.add(x);
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Now the weird thing is, my console outputted this

Found C is the same as B 
Found D is the same as A

Going through the connections
AC
BC
BD
AD
CG
BF
GF
CF
where label1 would be a, and label 2 c for the first one, it only happens on those two and is of course, giving me a invalid result.

Comment: Is this a homework problem?  if so, please tag it as homework.

Comment: It is for my A2 Computing coursework, so i am not sure if that is classified, its a personal project but for a course. I'll tag it just incase

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very repetitive, which makes it exposed to such crazy bugs. Why don't you make the followinrg additions:

In Node:

```
String normLabel() { return getLabel().toUpperCase(); }
```

In Connection:

```
public boolean matches(Connection other) {
  final String this1 = getNode(1).normLabel(), this2 = getNode(2).normLabel(),
               other1 = other.getNode(1).normLabel(), 
               other2 = other.getNode(2).normLabel();
    return this1.equals(other1) || this2.equals(other1) ||
           this1.equals(other2) || this2.equals(other2);
  }
```

Then your main code can collapse into the following:

```
private static List<Graph> caseForConnection(
    Connection consideredConnection, ArrayList<Graph> subTrees)
{
  final List<Graph> ret = new ArrayList<Graph>();
  for (Graph g : subTrees) {
    for (Connection c : g.getConnectionList()) {
      if (c.matches(consideredConnection)) {
        if (ret.contains(g)) throw new RuntimeException("Cycle Found");
        ret.add(g);
      }
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

There's a good chance the bug will just evaporate, but even if it doesn't, it'll be much easier to track down.

Comment: Thanks for the code, it still throws up the same thing as its showing the same case for the connection BC, which is throwing the cycle found exception, despite the fact it should just return a list of size 1.
If it helps i am loading the problem from a save file
where its in the format ID NODELABEL NODELABEL WEIGHT
 Thanks

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?yrl8848dwr4da86 
Here are .java files for all my stuff if it helps at all, i know its not great but i have tried to comment the majority of it if it helps you get an understanding

Comment: "You're comparing consideredConnection to each connection in g with c.matches(consideredConnection), where anything with just one similar node returns true, meaning anything with "C" or "A" in it will count as having two connections, even if it shares only one node" 

Was the problem thanks for all the help guys, completely fixed

Comment: Yes, I was wondering why you would be doing that. So the problem was not on the Java level, but on the algorihtm level. It is easily fixable in the code I gave you. If by any chance you found this code helpful, please accept the answer. That's the StackOverflow etiquette.